# ActiveMQ:Non persistent Topic Consumer doesnt close sometimes

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ 5.5 and have the following scenario

-Embedded Broker

-NonPersistent Producer and Topic

-A consumer of the topic.

The normal stuff is working - I publish to a topic and a subscriber consumes from it.

I've implemented a MessageListener, so when a consumer subscribes and unsubscribes, I print something to indicate that.
When I have to close the consumer, I just call it's close method.

Sometimes the consumer closes successfully - I see the log and memory usage is fine.

But sometimes it doesnt close, though I can see in the log that I called the close method.
This time in the log the MessageListener doesnt mention how the subcriber unsubscribed.
And as a result, the memory usage just goes up, because now publisher is sending messages to the topic and I've closed the consumer (which is not really closed) 
and stopped handling the messages.

So I'm not sure where and how to troubleshoot this issue......
I think this has something to do with asynch activemq worker threads and their behavior.

Below are all the classes related to ActiveMQ that i'm using..let me know if I should put out any additional code.

```
            public class Consumer {

              private MessageConsumer consumer;

              public Consumer(String brokerUrl, String topic, MessageListener ml) throws JMSException {

                ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

                //with straight through processing of messages
                //and optimized acknowledgement
                cf.setAlwaysSessionAsync(false);
                cf.setOptimizeAcknowledge(true);
                Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
                connection.start();

                //-- Use the default session
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                //-- Set the prefetch size for topics - by parsing a configuration parameter in
                // the name of the topic
                //-- topic=test.topic?consumer.prefetchSize=32766
                Topic topicObj = session.createTopic(topic);

                consumer = session.createConsumer(topicObj);

                //-- Attach the passed in message listener
                consumer.setMessageListener(ml);

              }

              /**
               * @return the consumer
               */
              public MessageConsumer getConsumer() {
                return consumer;
              }
            }   


            public class ConsumerAdvisoryListener implements MessageListener {

              private XMLLogUtil xlu;
              private MyLogger ml;

              public ConsumerAdvisoryListener() throws IOException{
                xlu=XMLLogUtil.getInstance();
                ml=xlu.getCustomLogger(ConsumerAdvisoryListener.class);
              }

              public void onMessage(Message message) {
                ActiveMQMessage msg = (ActiveMQMessage) message;
                DataStructure ds = msg.getDataStructure();
                if (ds != null) {
                  switch (ds.getDataStructureType()) {
                  case CommandTypes.CONSUMER_INFO:
                    ConsumerInfo consumerInfo = (ConsumerInfo) ds;
                    ml.info("Consumer '" + consumerInfo.getConsumerId()
                        + "' subscribed to '" + consumerInfo.getDestination()
                        + "'");
                    break;
                  case CommandTypes.REMOVE_INFO:
                    RemoveInfo removeInfo = (RemoveInfo) ds;
                    ConsumerId consumerId = ((ConsumerId) removeInfo.getObjectId());
                    ml.info("Consumer '" + consumerId + "' unsubscribed");
                    break;
                  default:
                    ml.info("Unkown data structure type");
                  }
                } else {
                  ml.info("No data structure provided");
                }
              }
            }


            public class EmbeddedBroker {

              /**
               * Singleton
               */
              private static EmbeddedBroker INSTANCE;
              private BrokerService broker; 

              /**
               * Return singleton instance
               * @return
               */
              public static EmbeddedBroker getInstance(){
                if(EmbeddedBroker.INSTANCE ==null){
                  throw new IllegalStateException("Not Initialized");
                }

                return INSTANCE;
              }

              /**
               * Initialize singleton instance.
               * 
               * @return
               * @throws Exception 
               */
              public static EmbeddedBroker initialize(String brokerName) throws Exception{
                if(EmbeddedBroker.INSTANCE ==null){
                  EmbeddedBroker.INSTANCE=new EmbeddedBroker(brokerName, false);
                }
                else{
                  throw new IllegalStateException("Already Initialized");
                }

                return INSTANCE;
              }

              /**
               * Initialize singleton instance.
               * 
               * @return
               * @throws Exception 
               */
              public static EmbeddedBroker initialize(String brokerName, boolean enableTCPConnector) throws Exception{
                if(EmbeddedBroker.INSTANCE ==null){
                  EmbeddedBroker.INSTANCE=new EmbeddedBroker(brokerName, enableTCPConnector);
                }
                else{
                  throw new IllegalStateException("Already Initialized");
                }

                return INSTANCE;
              }

              /**
               * Private constructor
               * @throws Exception 
               */
              private EmbeddedBroker(String brokerName, boolean enableTCPConnector) throws Exception{

                //-- By default a broker always listens on vm://<broker name>
                this.broker = new BrokerService();
                this.broker.setBrokerName(brokerName);

                //-- Enable Advisory Support.  Its true by default, but this is to explicitly mention it for documentation purposes
                this.broker.setAdvisorySupport(true);

                /* Create non-persistent broker to use inMemory Store,
                 * instead of KAHA or any other persistent store.
                 * See Section 4.6.1 of ActiveMQInAction  
                 */
                this.broker.setPersistent(false);

                //-- 64 MB
                this.broker.getSystemUsage().getMemoryUsage().setLimit(64*1024*1024);

                //-- Set the Destination policies
                PolicyEntry policy = new PolicyEntry();

                //-- Set a memory limit of 4mb for each destination
                policy.setMemoryLimit(4 * 1024 *1024);

                //-- Disable flow control
                policy.setProducerFlowControl(false);
                PolicyMap pMap = new PolicyMap();

                //-- Configure the policy
                pMap.setDefaultEntry(policy);
                this.broker.setDestinationPolicy(pMap);

                if(enableTCPConnector)
                  broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");

                //-- Start the Broker.
                this.broker.start();

              }

            }




            public class NonPersistentProducer {

              private final MessageProducer producer;
              private final Session session;

              public NonPersistentProducer(String brokerUrl, String topic) throws JMSException{
                //-- Tell the connection factory to connect to a broker and topic passed in.
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

                //-- Disable message copying
                cf.setCopyMessageOnSend(false);

                Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
                connection.start();

                session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                Topic topicObj = session.createTopic(topic);

                producer = session.createProducer(topicObj);

                //-- Send non-persistent messages
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

              }//-- Producer

              /**
               * @return the producer
               */
              public MessageProducer getProducer() {
                return producer;
              }

              /**
               * @return the session
               */
              public Session getSession() {
                return session;
              }



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The close (read documentation) method blocks till the receive or listener finishes. In my situation, my listener was getting lost due to an exception.  As long as the listener or receive complete successfully, the close will complete and consumer will be removed.